# Why doesn't filter_at work within ifelse?

Tags: r, if-statement, filter, dplyr

I'm working with a dataset of family relationships, with a row for each person and columns describing potential relationships (there is a father column, a mother column, a spouse column, etc.). The columns that I am having problems with are those listing the children of a given individal. I have these as columns titled child1, child2, etc.

I want the end result of the function I'm creating to be a smaller dataset that shows family relationships centered around a particular individual. Since the "child" columns are the ones I am having difficulty with, I'm focusing on the rows that will be included with the relationship column reading "parent."

I have code that allows me to filter to find the parents of any person in the dataset, and when I use it outside of the function, everything works fine. It gives me the parents of any individual whose name I put in place of `name`, no matter which of the child columns that individual is in.

```
dataset %>%
    filter_at(vars(matches("^child\\d+$")), any_vars(. == name))
```

The problem arises when I try to apply this code to my function. I get the following error message: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "quosures".`

```
test_function <- function(name, dataset) {
    exact_name <- paste("^", name, "$", sep = "")
    family_data <- data.frame(
        dataset %>%
            mutate(relationship = ifelse(
                filter_at(vars(matches("^child\\d+$")), any_vars(. == exact_name)), 
                "parent", 
                "other"
            )) %>%
            filter(relationship != other))
}
```

I'm guessing that it has something to do with the use of `filter_at` within `ifelse`. Is there a better way to get the results I want?

(The above is an abbreviated version of my function; I have other ifelse statements in the mutate function that give other relationships, but those don't depend on filter_at and are working fine.)

Comment: All dplyr verbs, including `filter`, return a full data frame. You can't currently put a data frame in a column of a tibble unless you wrap it in a list. Further, `ifelse` requires a boolean vector as its first parameter, and returns a vector stripped of any attributes. None of this is quite what you want. You _can_ use `if (...) {...} else {...}` in `mutate` if you like, but it's rarely necessary or a good idea.

Comment: `filter_at` requires a data source to be passed as the first parameter which you are doing with `%>%` in the first case, but not with the `mutate()` call. It would be easier to help you if you should included a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: There's also a `"` missing at the end of the regex in the function, though running it should reveal the string isn't closed.